# Determine value of '$a$' for which the system is inconsistent and has infinitely many solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Consider the matrix $A$, to be equal to:
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\-1&4&3\\2&-2&a\end{bmatrix}

Then we can rewrite this as:
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&6&4\\2&-2&a\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&1&2/3\\2&-2&a\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&1&2/3\\0&-6&a-2\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&1&2/3\\0&0&a+2\end{bmatrix}

Now consider the system $Ax=0$. **If** $\mathbf{a = -2}$, then $x_3$ is a free variable, because a+2 turns to zero. The solution becomes: 
$$x_1 = (1/3)x_3$$
$$x_2 = -(2/3)x_3$$
$$x_3 = free$$ 
**If** $\mathbf{a}$ **does not equal 2** , then the system seems to have trivial solutions every time, because you divide $a+2$ by itself, which becomes $1$, regardless of the value of $a$. The solutions become:
$$x_1 = 0$$
$$x_2 = 0$$
$$x_3 = 0$$

But then how can you determine when the system $Ax=0$ is inconsistent or has infinitely many solutions? What mistake have I made? Could someone provide me your own method if my method seems to be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are talking of the homogeneous system of equations, right?

The solution for $a=-2$ is correct. As you have said, for $a\neq -2$, the only solution is $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$.

The dimension of the solution space is thus $0$ if $a=-2$ and $1$ otherwise.

Comment: OP is talking about infinitely many solutions, not infinitely many independent  solutions

Comment: Doesn't that mean that you cannot choose a value of a for the system to be inconsistent or have infinitely many solutions?

Comment: @Stallmp There is always at least one solution for homogeneous systems of equations (the trivial solution $0$); there are infinitely many solutions for $a=-2$.

Comment: Oh yeah I see, because $x_3$ is a free variable, which implies that there are infinitely many solutions right? So the system is never inconsistent regardless of a?

Comment: @Stallmp Yes, there is always a solution.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! So would you say my explanation and method are correct?

Comment: @Stallmp Your calculations are correct.

Comment: @Stallmp: When $a=-2$, as you wrote, you have as solutions $S = \{ (v/3, -2v/3, v): v \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 1):

$Ax=0$ has a unique solution if $\det(A)\neq 0$ and it has infintely many solutions if $\det(A)= 0$ (any multiple of a solution is also a solution). In this case $\det(A)=0$ iff $a =-2$.

Comment: Alright I see, thank you. Would this imply that inconsistency is not possible with systems Ax = 0 ?

Comment: Yes, the zero vector is always a solution, so there is no question of inconsistency.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot!